# Location listener is working the in emulator but not working in the real device

Tags: java, android

I am using this piece of code to get user coordinates and then send the coordinates to the geocoding API. my code works fine in the emulator since I am sending the coordinates through emulator control but when it comes to a real device I am not getting any response. 
I have given the necessary permissions in the manifest. I have tried all the necessary ways but I got no positive result. please help me in this regard I need to submit my project within few days.

```
private void location()
    {
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Intent i = new Intent("LocationUpdates");
                i.putExtra("LAT", location.getLatitude() + "");
                i.putExtra("LNG", location.getLongitude() + "");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.d("LAT", location.getLatitude() + "");
                Log.d("LNG", location.getLongitude() + "");
                locationData = location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude();
                final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" +(longitude)+ ","+(latitude)+"&key-AIzaSyDebBZIppRUR_r5GDNFCcK8o4qcU-Yd3bg", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    address = response.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
                                    t.setText(address);
                                    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(address,",");
                                    road = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                                    city = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                                    country = stringTokenizer.nextToken();

                                    updateLocation();
                                    Intent sigin = new Intent(Discover.this, NearbyUsers.class);
                                    startActivity(sigin);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }
                        });
                        requestQueue.add(request);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);
        }else{

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 0, locationListener);
            }
        }

    }


    private void updateLocation() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Finding the Location...");
            progressDialog.show();
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    Constants.URL_ADDRESS,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            progressDialog.hide();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("email", a);
                    params.put("address", address);
                    params.put("road", road);
                    params.put("city", city);
                    params.put("country", country);
                    return params;
                }
            };

            RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    }
```

Comment: few things which you can check, if you are running on a device with api >=23, then runtime permission is given to your app plus gps is on or off.

Comment: those are all right

Comment: @sheeno Hey, I know that is an old problem but did you find a solution? :D facing same problem.